# DNS issue for new domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Yesterday I bought a new domain: dragostepentruadevar.ro.

Also I've deployed my play! application to http://www.playapps.net/ and on my slot I have the ip: http://92.243.20.204.

Well, I have added this IP as nameserver to my domain but seems that it is not working: http://dragostepentruadevar.ro/

What is strange for me is that if I query in linux for my nameservers they have a different ips:

```
play@s552:~/storage/mysql/mysql$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 217.70.184.225
nameserver 217.70.184.226
```

So which of these should I add to the domain registration ns? Because now I've added:
ns.dragostepentruadevar.ro:92.243.20.204

Thanks.

UPDATE: Thanks to all for the answers. In the end, I've used a free dns management tool, added their ns to my domain, and added two A records to point to my ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing nameserver with DNS record.

In simple terms

- each domain has a nameserver record which points to a DNS server that hosts the details about how to map the domain to IP addresses and can be queried by DNS clients
- the nameserver itself contains a set of mappings e.g. dragostepentruadevar.ro => 92.243.20.204 or www.dragostepentruadevar.ro => 92.243.20.204

It sounds like you have set up the nameserver to be your webserver address rather than set it to a DNS serevr that then points your domain name to your webserver.

Comment: This basically means that ns.dragostepentruadevar.ro should point to "217.70.184.225" in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your Domain management control panel provided by Domain registrar and follow the following steps

1. Select "Manage DNS" or some Alternate option
2. Create an " A " record of "dragostepentruadevar.ro" to 92.243.20.204

The name-servers 217.70.184.225 and 217.70.184.226 are used to resolve every query generated from your box, it is not connected to occurring problem.

Regards,

Asif

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for DNS issues is IntoDNS (I also use DNS stuff but it is not free).

http://www.intodns.com/dragostepentruadevar.ro

Appears there is a mismatch between your nameservers at the registrar and those on your server.  These need to be the same.

These are listed on your server but not at the registrar.

ns4.afraid.org  ['174.128.246.102']   [TTL=86400]
ns3.afraid.org  ['72.20.15.62']   [TTL=86400]

This could cause some issues with DNS.

Otherwise, looks like you may have fixed your domain.